# Flickering in Java awt (how to use a buffer?)

Tags: java, awt, buffer

Part of my Code is this paint method:

```
public void paint(Graphics g) {
    super.paint(g);
    refreshSize();
    paintSquares(g);
    if (drawGrid) {
        drawGrid(g);
    }
}
```

how can I use a buffer to stop it from flickering?

Comment: 1. don't to use paint to AWT without special reasons, 2. use Swing instead, 3. depends of a few factors, 4.for better help sooner post an SSCCE/MCVE, short, runnable, compilable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can reduce flicker by overwriting the update(Graphics g) method with an empty implementation (update's default implementation renders the background). If you do this, you must ensure you paint the entire area of the component.

(Note: Overwriting update only really helps on a Frame - other components will still flicker because the containing Frame)

That said, do yourself a favor and switch to Swing.

Edit: Digging around a bit, the background rendering occurs in the update() implementation of java.awt.Container (Frame being a subclass of Container ofc). Combined with backbuffer rendering (that you would need to handle yourself, e.g. a BufferedImage) you could get to what Swing automatically delivers with AWT.